# Implementing encryption in Entity Framework Core models for SQL database

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am using EF Core 2.2 and I need to store sensitive data in the SQL database. Always Encrypted is not supported with EF Core yet so I am using the Microsoft Data Protection API to encrypt and decrypt data as it goes into and out of the database. This allows the controllers to have access to it as they need it. However, most of my data is integers but encrypted forms need to be strings. So I made a model that has the `[NotMapped]` attributes on the unencrypted values so that only the encrypted ones are in the database and encrypt/decrypt them in the get;set;. This is opening some new issues below...

When I try and declare a new Aritaurian object, I get the error:

> There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'provider' of 'Aritaurian.Aritaurian(IDataProtectionProvider)'

I conceptually understand why I get this error but, in reality am not sure what to do about it. I understand that it's being treated like a method so when I initialize the model I need to pass something to it... however, it's just the initializer for the DPAPI. Also, the bigger issue is when I try and `add-migrations`, EF tries to add the `IDataProtectionProvider` into the database but it is not a property.

At this point, I am in over my head and almost 100% sure there is a better way to implement what I want than what I am doing.

```cs
using System;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection;

namespace ConclaveNet.Models
{
    public class Aritaurian
    {
        private IDataProtector _protector;

        public Aritaurian(IDataProtectionProvider provider)
        {
            _protector = provider.CreateProtector(GetType().FullName);
        }

        public int Id { get; set; }

//Trying to store the discord unique identifier in an encrypted format. The datatype is a ulong by default.
        [Required]
        [NotMapped]
        public ulong Snowflake
        {
            get { return ulong.Parse(_protector.Unprotect(Encrypted_Snowflake)); }
            set { Encrypted_Snowflake = _protector.Protect(value.ToString());  }
        }

        public string Encrypted_Snowflake { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I expect that when I call

```
Aritaurian = _context.Aritaurians.singleordefault();
```

`Aritaurian.Snowflake` will actually reference the `encrypted_snowflake` and decrypt it, parse it to ulong and be available for use.

What is happening is that I do not get that far.

Comment: Can you explain what scenario you are trying to mitigate by encrypting things? Are you afraid your database admin might leak the data?

Comment: First of all, do you *really* need Always Encrypted? You can encrypt the data on disk using Transparent Data Encryption. You can use SSL encryption on the connection to protect the database connection. If you want to protect personal data from disclosure you can use dynamic masking

Comment: You can try using the new [Microsoft.Data.SqlClient](https://github.com/dotnet/SqlClient/blob/master/release-notes/1.0/1.0.md) provider for Always Encrypted connections together eg with Dapper or plain ADO.NET command objects. EF Core 3 will use Microsoft.Data.SqlClient to for AE support anyway. The current EF Core versions use System.Data.SqlClient which will be replaced by Microsoft.Data.SqlClient so they probably won't get AE support

Comment: I may have a misconception about the way things work leading to an incorrect implementation. @nvoigt I am sure even in passing you have seen the lengths people will go to in games such as EVE-Online to procure information. The idea behind storing all the data encrypted is that if you do manage to SQL inject then you can't access the data. Furthermore, the people on the web-team are tursted now but if they leave us won't be able to snoop around into personal data before departing without writing code to get it from the database. and deploying code to the server. We prevent that from happening.

Comment: Everything is on Azure in terms of the keyvault, app, and database. We use an SSL to protect the connection and keyvault to protect the encryption keys/database connection string. The hope was to encrypt the data at rest in SQL and still be able to use entity framework. Were using DPAPI because we currently are using that to encrypt data passed to the view and claims stored in the cookie.

Comment: If I can't fgure out a workaround, then we will just need to wait for EF core 3.0 to add the AE from Microsoft.Data.SQLClient.